# Where can I download Grails 1.1 from?

Tags: grails

If you check the 
[Official](https://grails.org/download) page,This version is unavailable. It says that I'ts [forbidden](http://dist.codehaus.org/grails/grails-src-1.1.zip) .
Do you know another place where I can Find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always check the old https://grails.org/dist/ as it appears to be there and downloadable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait to select your answer

Comment: The link given in the answer looks good, but at the moment all 1.1.x versions I've tried to download (from different internet connections) have been corrupt. Only about 23MB or so out of the 33-34MB file size comes down. Can anyone confirm that the files being served at the moment are actually usable?

Comment: You can now find it at github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v1.1.1.